# Is there any way to get the coefficient values from an SMT expression?

Tags: z3, smt

I would like to know if there is some SMT command to get the coefficient values associated to an expression as the following

```
(assert (>= (+ x (* (/ -1 2) y)) 0.0))
```

So getting the values 1 and -0.5.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

The SMT-LIB2 command language does generally have any facilities for programming.
Z3 exposes a python API that enables you to write down formulas in a readable way.
Furthermore you can use python and the API to write functions that walk expressions.
There is an online version of the Python API on http://rise4fun.com/z3py 
and there is an associated tutorial that goes over main features of that interface.